# No puedo instalar bcrypt

Tags: nodejs

Ejecuto el comando `npm install bcrypt` y este es el error que muestra, muchas gracias por la ayuda:

> bcrypt@3.0.6 install C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\bcrypt
>   node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
>   node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404):
>   https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v3.0.6/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.6-node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
>   node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.6 and
>   node@12.3.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile
>   with node-gyp) MSBUILD : error MSB1009: El archivo de proyecto no
>   existe. Modificador: build/binding.sln gyp ERR! build error gyp ERR!
>   stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit
>   code: 1 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13) gyp ERR!
>   stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:272:12) gyp ERR! System Windows_NT
>   10.0.17134 gyp ERR! command "C:\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "build" "--fallback-to-build"
>   "--module=C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node"
>   "--module_name=bcrypt_lib"
>   "--module_path=C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding"
>   "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0"
>   "--node_napi_label=node-v72" gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\bcrypt gyp ERR! node -v v12.3.0 gyp
>   ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 gyp ERR! not ok node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\nodejs\node.exe
>   C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build
>   --fallback-to-build --module=C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node
>   --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.
>   (C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
>   (internal/child_process.js:1021:16) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134 node-pre-gyp ERR!
>   command "C:\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp"
>   "install" "--fallback-to-build" node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\bcrypt node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v
>   v12.3.0 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0 node-pre-gyp ERR!
>   not ok Failed to execute 'C:\nodejs\node.exe
>   C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build
>   --fallback-to-build --module=C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node
>   --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1) npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\package.json' npm WARN
>   system32 No description npm WARN system32 No repository field. npm
>   WARN system32 No README data npm WARN system32 No license field.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.6
>   install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build` npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.6 install script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Robert
>   Mendez\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-14T02_47_09_209Z-debug.log

Comment: Hola, no es común, pero normalmente tiene que ver con la versión de `node-gyp`, la cual por alguna razón tiene algo diferente cuando se actualiza la versión de Node. Una forma en la que normalmente soluciono este problema, y no sé si es lo que buscas, es instalar `bcrypt@latest`, eso sobreescribirá o actualizará la versión que tengas y realizará el compilado usando una versión _¿fresca?_ de `node-gyp`. Intenta hacerlo así y comenta los resultados. Esta no es una solución real al problema, más bien es un atajo. Saludos

Comment: Hola siempre me salio el mismo erros

Comment: MSBUILD : error MSB1009: El archivo de proyecto no existe.
Modificador: build/binding.sln

Answer (score 0):

para que no de error en el sistema, debemos instalar python nueva version, y npm install -g node-gyp en nueva consola de windows.
se solucionara error..

luego

npm install bcrypt -- save
se instalara corectamente

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver ese problema podrías instalar python antes de hacer la instalación de bcrypt.

Otra opción es instalar bcryptjs, se utiliza de la misma manera que bcrypt.

Incluso se suele hacer el **require** o **import** con el nombre de la variable **bcrypt** (así lo sugiere la documentación) y luego se hace el `bcrypt.hash` o el `bcrypt.compare`.

Ejemplo:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
```

Para hashear:

```
bcrypt.hash(inputPassword, salt)
```

Para comparar:

```
bcrypt.compare(inputPassword, currentPassword)
```

Se puede resolver con callbacks, async/await o then/catch.

También con hashSync y compareSync aunque si revisas la documentación de bcrypt verás que recomienda no usar estos últimos dos.

---

Link a documentación de bcryptjs:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs